# How tell Stylus to Not interpret a CSS property as a mixin?

Tags: css, right-to-left, stylus

I'm adding support for Right-to-Left languages, and want to redefine `margin-left` to `margin-right` etc. (There's [`margin-inline-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline-start) and `margin-inline-end` etc but they're not yet supported in Edge.) So, with Stylus, I tried this:

```
margin-right()
  margin-left: arguments;

margin-left()
  margin-right: arguments;
```

However, when Stylus sees `margin-right: 10px`, Stylus changes to `margin-left: 10px` and then re-interprets `margin-left` as `margin-right: 10px` — the end result: nothing happens.

(If I instead redefine to `margin-TEST-left: ...`, then, works as expected: `margin-right: 10px` becomes `margin-TEST-left: 10px`.)

How do I tell Stylus to interpret `margin-left: arguments` as the "real" `margin-left` and not a function call to the `margin-left()` mixin?

Comment: In which cases do you need it to be the mixin and not the actual values? It's not exactly the answer you're looking for, but I like following a naming convention for my variables and mixins that just prefixes them with a $ sign so it's obvious to me. So `$margin-right` when you need the mixin

Comment: @webdevdani — when building a RTL styles bundle, then, this needs to be the mixin, always, except for the two `margin-(left|right): arguments;` lines above. And, when building a left-to-right bundle, then, I won't include these mixins at all.  — I like the `$` prefix idea and that's how I usually do. In this case though, by defining the mixins without `$`, I could add RTL support to my web app, without changing any single line of the old existing Stylus code (adding `$` at 1000 of places would have been error prone, nice to have avoided that :- )).

Comment: How are you determining if its RTL mode or not? I have a potential idea

Comment: @webdevdani — that's a per discussion forum config value. All text in a forum, is supposed to be in the same language. E.g. everything everywhere in Hebrew or everything in Arabic etc.

Comment: do you have access to that info from within the CSS? Like are you adding a class or passing this in somehow?